# Gcc throws error when I try to compile the test folder in libburn

Tags: c

[Libburn](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/multimedia/libburn.html)

So after I installed libburn I went to the test folder which comes with the libburn's code.Then there is the libburner.c file.I try to compile it with gcc(gcc libburn.c -o outputfile) but it gives me these error even though the header file exists.

```
libburner.c:(.text+0xb17): undefined reference to `burn_disc_create'
/usr/bin/ld: libburner.c:(.text+0xb20): undefined reference to `burn_session_create'
/usr/bin/ld: libburner.c:(.text+0xb3c): undefined reference to `burn_disc_add_session'
/usr/bin/ld: libburner.c:(.text+0xb4d): undefined reference to `burn_track_create'
/usr/bin/ld: libburner.c:(.text+0xb84): undefined reference to `burn_track_define_data'
/usr/bin/ld: libburner.c:(.text+0xc4d): undefined reference to `burn_fd_source_new'
/usr/bin/ld: libburner.c:(.text+0xcd1): undefined reference to `burn_fifo_source_new'
/usr/bin/ld: libburner.c:(.text+0xd39): undefined reference to `burn_track_set_source'
/usr/bin/ld: libburner.c:(.text+0xd81): undefined reference to `burn_session_add_track'
/usr/bin/ld: libburner.c:(.text+0xdad): undefined reference to `burn_source_free'
/usr/bin/ld: libburner.c:(.text+0xdd7): undefined reference to `burn_disc_get_status'
/usr/bin/ld: libburner.c:(.text+0xe23): undefined reference to `burn_disc_erasable'
/usr/bin/ld: libburner.c:(.text+0xeac): undefined reference to `burn_write_opts_new'
/usr/bin/ld: libburner.c:(.text+0xec1): undefined reference to `burn_write_opts_set_perform_opc'
/usr/bin/ld: libburner.c:(.text+0xedc): undefined reference to `burn_write_opts_set_multi'
/usr/bin/ld: libburner.c:(.text+0xf05): undefined reference to `burn_write_opts_set_simulate'
/usr/bin/ld: libburner.c:(.text+0xf1e): undefined reference to `burn_drive_set_speed'
/usr/bin/ld: libburner.c:(.text+0xf2f): undefined reference to `burn_write_opts_set_underrun_proof'
/usr/bin/ld: libburner.c:(.text+0xf4b): undefined reference to `burn_write_opts_auto_write_type'
/usr/bin/ld: libburner.c:(.text+0xfb4): undefined reference to `burn_set_signal_handling'
/usr/bin/ld: libburner.c:(.text+0xfe1): undefined reference to `burn_disc_write'
/usr/bin/ld: libburner.c:(.text+0x1001): undefined reference to `burn_drive_get_status'
/usr/bin/ld: libburner.c:(.text+0x1114): undefined reference to `burn_fifo_inquire_status'
/usr/bin/ld: libburner.c:(.text+0x119d): undefined reference to `burn_drive_get_status'
/usr/bin/ld: libburner.c:(.text+0x11b9): undefined reference to `burn_is_aborting'
/usr/bin/ld: libburner.c:(.text+0x1236): undefined reference to `burn_write_opts_free'
/usr/bin/ld: libburner.c:(.text+0x1266): undefined reference to `burn_source_free'
/usr/bin/ld: libburner.c:(.text+0x128d): undefined reference to `burn_track_free'
/usr/bin/ld: libburner.c:(.text+0x12af): undefined reference to `burn_source_free'
/usr/bin/ld: libburner.c:(.text+0x12c2): undefined reference to `burn_session_free'
/usr/bin/ld: libburner.c:(.text+0x12d5): undefined reference to `burn_disc_free'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cchZ1bZA.o: in function `main':
libburner.c:(.text+0x1a52): undefined reference to `burn_initialize'
/usr/bin/ld: libburner.c:(.text+0x1a7c): undefined reference to `burn_msgs_set_severities'
/usr/bin/ld: libburner.c:(.text+0x1a92): undefined reference to `burn_set_signal_handling'
/usr/bin/ld: libburner.c:(.text+0x1c6e): undefined reference to `burn_drive_release'
/usr/bin/ld: libburner.c:(.text+0x1c7b): undefined reference to `burn_is_aborting'
/usr/bin/ld: libburner.c:(.text+0x1c8d): undefined reference to `burn_abort_pacifier'
/usr/bin/ld: libburner.c:(.text+0x1c9a): undefined reference to `burn_abort'
/usr/bin/ld: libburner.c:(.text+0x1cc9): undefined reference to `burn_finish'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Please help me.

Comment: "I try to compile it with gcc". How? What exact command did you run? Please add it to the question.

Comment: Done @kaylum...I have edited the question

Comment: You need to link against the library.

Comment: @thebusybee Please could you ellaborate that a bit more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Commonly and in short terms there are three tools involved when you create software in C:

1. An **editor** to write the source code.
2. A **compiler** to translate the source code into object code, which consists mainly of machine code, whose references are not yet resolved.
3. A **linker** to link (to bind) separated parts of object code into an executable, which has all references resolved.

You can use any application as an **editor** that can create source code in the right format. I even heard about a guy using Microsoft Word for this, because the Notepad of that time could not handle files larger than 64 KB.

You use GCC apparently as **compiler** and **linker**.

You didn't mention any compilation problem, it apparently reported no errors. Anyway, the source code of the test application contains the line `#include "libburn.h"` or similar. This way the compiler knows that there are functions the application can call, and it can check that the application calls none or more of these functions in the right way.

You wrote that your command line to build is `gcc libburn.c -o outputfile`, which I think is wrong. It should be `gcc libburner.c -o outputfile`.

This command line is missing the argument to **link** against the library `libburn`. Consequently the linker reports a lot of "undefined references".

Add `-lburn` to the command line, or what else is appropriate. You didn't mention the host and target system of your build, too, and it depends.

*Note: The command line contains both steps in one: compiling and linking. Please take some minutes to research and to learn how to use GCC from the command line.*